# Is there any major effect if I upgrade jQuery library from v1.8.3 to v1.9.0

Tags: jquery

Earlier I was using  jquery library v1.8.3. Now I have implement lazyload, but it is not working for IE7/8. After upgrading from v1.8.3 to v1.9.0, it working fine.

Is there any major effect if I upgrade jQuery library from v1.8.3 to v1.9.0.

Updated: because I am using jQuery on most of the page and it is working fine with jQuery library v1.8.3

Please suggest!

Comment: While you're at it, upgrade to `1.10.1` instead of `1.9.1`

Comment: I can, but just thinking how much it will effect my old jQuery functionality.

Comment: Why don't you just try? See the answer TheifMaster gave you those are not a lot of changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are. Please read the [relevant documentation](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) (which, by the way, is the **first** result when [Googling for "upgrading jquery"](https://www.google.com/search?q=upgrading%20jquery)) since it's way too much to include in an answer here.

Some relevant changes are:

- `.toggle(function, function, ... )` removed
- `jQuery.browser()` removed
- `.live()` removed
- `.die()` removed
- you need to use `.prop()` to change properties like *checked* or *disabled*.

If any of the changes break your code you *could* add [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) to undo most breaking changes. However, this is a bad idea. Instead, you should update your code to comply with the changes mentioned in the linked page.